# Show that the system has a unique solution on any interval where it is defined.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $g,f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, $f$ being lipschitzian. Show that the system

$\left\{\begin{array}{l} 
x'=f(x), & x(t_0)=x_0\\
y'=g(x)y, & y(t_0)=y_0 
\end{array}
\right.$

has a unique solution on any interval (where it is defined). Can one eliminate the hypothesis that $f$ is Lipschitzian and obtain the same conclusion?

Comment: You need to show a modicum of effort.

Comment: @copper.hat if I had any idea how to start, of course I would show it, but I don't have the slightest idea.

Comment: Are you familiar with and existence & uniqueness theorems?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, of course